# проверка на принадлежность символа строки к массиву

Tags: javascript

не выполняется проверка длины добавляемого символа в алфавит `if(str.length == 1 ){...}`(должен добавляться только один символ)  и не выполняется проверка 
`for(var i=1; i<w2.length-1; i++){ if(term.indexOf(w2.charAt(i))== -1){` и `for(var i=0; i<w2.length-2; i++){ if(term.indexOf(w2.charAt(i))== -1){`. Т.е. одна и та же добавляемая строка должна проходить проверку. 1) все символы строки, кроме первого, соответствуют элементам массива term. 2) все символы строки, кроме последнего соответствуют элементам массива term.

```js
var terminal = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var term=document.getElementById('terminal').innerHTML = terminal;

var noterminal = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'];
var noterm = document.getElementById('noterminal').innerHTML = noterminal;

function pushTerminal(){
    var x = document.getElementById('newTerminal');
    var str = term.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    var str2 = noterm.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
    if(str.length == 1 ){
    if(str == -1 && str2== -1) {
            term.push(document.getElementById("inputAdd").value);
            x.innerHTML = term.join();
             }else{
               alert("Элемент уже существует");
            }

        }else{
            alert("Необходимо ввести только один символ!");
        }
}

var changeStringFromRules = [];
var changeStringToRules = [];
function pushRules(){
    var w1 = document.getElementById("inputw1").value;
    var w2 = document.getElementById("inputw2").value;
    var firstIn = term.indexOf(w2.charAt(0)) != -1;
    var lastIn = term.indexOf(w2.charAt(w2.length-1)) !=-1;
    var checkLettersTerm = true;
    var typeGrammar;
    for(var i=1; i<w2.length - 2; i++){
        if(term.indexOf(w2.charAt(i))==-1){
            innerIn = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(w1.length == 1){
        if(innerIn && firstIn != lastIn){
            if(innerIn && firstIn){
                typeGrammar = 'Грамматика типа 3';
            }else if(innerIn && lastIn){
                typeGrammar = 'Грамматика типа 3';
            } else{
                typeGrammar = 'Грамматика КС';
            }
        }else if(w1.length!=1 && term.indexOf(w1.charAt(0))!=-1 || noterm.indexOf(w1.charAt(0))!=-1) {
            typeGrammar = 'Грамматика КЗ';
        }
    }

    // if(w1.length == 1 && noterm.indexOf(w1)!=-1){
    //     if(noterm.indexOf(w2.charAt(0))!=-1 ){
    //          for(var i=1; i<w2.length-1; i++){
    //             if(term.indexOf(w2.charAt(i))== -1){
    //                 checkLettersTerm = false;
    //                 typeGrammar = 'Грамматика типа 3';
    //                 alert('Грамматика типа 3');
    //                 console.log('w2', w2);
    //             }
    //         }
    //
    //     }else if(noterm.indexOf(w2.charAt(w2.length-1))!=-1){
    //         for(var i=0; i<w2.length-2; i++){
    //             if(term.indexOf(w2.charAt(i))== -1){
    //                 checkLettersTerm = false;
    //                 typeGrammar = 'Грамматика типа 3';
    //                 alert('Грамматика типа 3');
    //
    //             }
    //         }
    //     } else {
    //         typeGrammar = 'Грамматика КС';
    //         alert('Контестно-свободная');
    //     }
    // }else if(w1.length!=1 && term.indexOf(w1.charAt(0))!=-1 || noterm.indexOf(w1.charAt(0))!=-1){
    //     typeGrammar = 'Грамматика КЗ';
    //     alert('Контекстно-зависимая');
    // }


    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = w1+'-->'+w2 +' '+ typeGrammar;
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);

    var removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
    removeBtn.type = "button";
    removeBtn.value = "Удалить";
    removeBtn.onclick = remove;
    li.appendChild(removeBtn);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);

}
function remove(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    el.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
    <div class="terminal">
        <h2>Терминальный алфавит: </h2>
        <div id="terminal"></div>
        <h2>Новый Терминальный алфавит: </h2>
        <div id="newTerminal"></div>
        <div class="addTerminal">
            <h3>Добавление терминала</h3>
            <form>
                <input id ="inputAdd" type="text">
                <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="pushTerminal()">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="noterminal">
        <h2>Нетерминальный алфавит: </h2>
        <div id="noterminal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="addRules">
    <h3>Добавить правило</h3>
    <form>
        <label>w1:</label><input id="inputw1" type="text"><label> --> w2:</label><input id="inputw2" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="pushRules(this)">
    </form>
    <h3>Правила:</h3>
    <div class="container_rules">
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = ['D', 'A', 'Z', 'L'];
//var arr = document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = arr;

if(arr.indexOf(w2.charAt(0))!=-1 || arr.indexOf(w2.charAt(w2.length-1))!=-1){

  var allInArray2 = true;
  for (var i = 1; i < w2.length - 1; i++) }
    if (array2.indexOf(w2.charAt(i)) == -1) {
      allInArray2 = false;
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

*Update*

Давайте попробуем еще раз.

```js
function strangeCheck(array, str) {
  var firstIn = array.indexOf(str.charAt(0)) != -1;
  var lastIn = array.indexOf(str.charAt(str.length - 1)) != -1;

  var innerIn = true;
  for (var i = 1; i < str.length - 2; i++) {
    if (array.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1) {
      innerIn = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  //console.log(firstIn, innerIn, lastIn);
  
  if (innerIn && firstIn != lastIn) {
    if (innerIn && firstIn) {
      // все символы строки, кроме последнего соответствуют элементам массива term
      return "all but the last";
    }
    if (innerIn && lastIn) {
      // все символы строки, кроме первого, соответствуют элементам массива term
      return "all but the first";
    }
  }
  
  return "none of the two good cases";
}

var chars = ['a','b','v','c'];
console.log(strangeCheck(chars, 'abZav'));
console.log(strangeCheck(chars, 'ZALD'));
console.log(strangeCheck(chars, 'cab'));
console.log(strangeCheck(chars, 'Zcav'));
console.log(strangeCheck(chars, 'acbD'));
```

Comment: Хм, а если разный регистр?

Comment: @Other хм, в вопросе про регистр ничего нет.

Comment: Да Вы просто будущее не видите :)

Comment: @vita_run "остальных элементов" - остальных символов строки, то есть каждого из них, или всего оставшегося куска строки, как целого? Вы не стеняйтесь использовать больше слов :).

Comment: а если нужно проверить остальные символы на принадлежность к другому массиву? if(array.indexOf(w2.charAt(0))!=-1){
            if(array2.indexOf(w2.substring(1,length))!=-1){
                alert('ok')
            }else{alert('error');}

Comment: каждого из них)

Comment: объясните,пожалуйста, разве не нужно разграничить условия проверки принадлежности символа к массиву array? если выполнять проверку для остальных символов, то получается, что если добавляю строку, где первый символ принадлежит array, то цикл будет идти от первого до последнего индекса, а если последний символ принадлежит array, то цикл с 0 до предпоследнего. а так получается что всегда проходится с первого, до  последнего

Comment: Вы не захотели внятно объяснить, какого поведения хотите добиться при каких условиях. Я могу об этом только догадываться. И хотя я умею очень хорошо догадываться, нам обоим было бы проще, если бы Вы подробно объяснили, что Вам надо. Лучше - в вопросе.

Comment: Грамматика типа 3: в inputw1 должен находиться единственный символ из noterminal, а в inputw2 цепочка из символов из termianl и символа из neterminal, который может быть либо первый,либо последний (например, D-->Lacb, A-->Dca).

Comment: @Igor, Вы извините, я не видела Ваших изменений. Что-то мне прям не дается эта задача(((  окончательно запуталась. изменила описание. если не сложно, посмотрите,пожалуйста, где ошибаюсь

Comment: @vita_run Решайте задачу по частям. Давайте сконцентрируемся на том, что я Вам написал. Есть функция `strangeCheck`, которая принимает массив букв и строку. Вы можете привести пример входных параметров, когда эта функция работает не так, как Вам надо?

Comment: @Igor, входные параметры, при которых функция будет работать не так как надо: abZav, ZALD, cab. Подходят любые варианты, где первый или последний символ не принадлежит массиву `chars`.

Comment: @vita_run Так, кто-то из нас не слышит собеседника. У функции *два* параметра - массив и строка. Приведите пример, включающий массив, строку и ожидаемый результат, когда этот результат не такой, какой возвращает моя функция `strangeCheck`.

Comment: @Igor, ойй. `array = ['a','b','v','c']`.  добавляемая строка:`abZav` или `ZALD` или `cab` => сообщение `строка не соответствует массиву`. добавляемая строка: `Zcav` => сообщение `тип1`. добавляемая строка: `acbD` =>сообщение `тип2`

Comment: @Igor,  а какая разница строчные они или заглавные? первый или последний символ строки  должен быть элементом массива `noterminal`, а остальные должны быть элементами массива `term`.

Comment: @vita_run Я добавил Ваши данные в пример. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в моем ответе.